# Fine tuning pretrained model in keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I want to use a pretrained imagenet VGG16 model in keras and add my own small convnet on top. I am only interested in the features, not the predictions

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np
import os
from keras.models import Model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
```

load images from directory (the dir contains 4 images)

```
IF = '/home/ubu/files/png/'
files = os.listdir(IF)

imgs = [img_to_array(load_img(IF + p, target_size=[224,224])) for p in files]
im = np.array(imgs)
```

load the base model, preprocess input and get the features

```
base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

x = preprocess_input(aa)
features = base_model.predict(x)
```

this works, and I get the features for my images on the pretrained VGG.

I now want to finetune the model and add some convolutional layers.
I read https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html and https://keras.io/applications/ but cannot quite bring them together.

adding my model on top:

```
x = base_model.output
x = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
feat = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
```

building the complete model

```
model_complete = Model(input=base_model.input, output=feat)
```

stop base layers from being learned

```
for layer in base_model.layers:
layer.trainable = False
```

new model

```
model_complete.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', 
          loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

now fit the new model, the model is 4 images and [1,0,1,0] are the class labels.
But this is obviously wrong:

```
model_complete.fit_generator((x, [1,0,1,0]), samples_per_epoch=100, nb_epoch=2)

ValueError: output of generator should be a tuple (x, y, sample_weight) or (x, y). Found: None
```

How is this done?

How would I do it if I only wanted to replace the last convolutional block (conv block5 in VGG16) instead of adding something?

How would I only train the bottleneck features?

The features output `features` has shape (4, 512, 7, 7). There are four images, but what is in the other dimensions? How would I reduce that to a (1,x) array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Fitting model**

The problem with your generator code is that the fit_generator method expects a generator function to generate the data for fitting which you don't provide.
You can either define a generator as done in the tutorial that you have linked to or create the data and labels yourself and fit your model yourself:

```
model_complete.fit(images, labels, batch_size=100, nb_epoch=2)
```

where images are your generated training images and labels are the corresponding labels.

**Removing last layer**

Assuming you have a model variable and the "pop" method described below, you can do `model = pop(model)` to remove the last layer.

**Training only specific layers**
As you have done in your code, you can do:

```
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
```

Then you can "unfreeze" and layer that you want by changing their `trainable` property to `True`.

**Changing dimensions**

To change the output to a 1D array you can use the [Flatten layer](https://keras.io/layers/core/#flatten)

---

***The pop method***

```
def pop(model):
    '''Removes a layer instance on top of the layer stack.
    This code is thanks to @joelthchao https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2371#issuecomment-211734276
    '''
    if not model.outputs:
        raise Exception('Sequential model cannot be popped: model is empty.')
    else:
        model.layers.pop()
        if not model.layers:
            model.outputs = []
            model.inbound_nodes = []
            model.outbound_nodes = []
        else:
            model.layers[-1].outbound_nodes = []
            model.outputs = [model.layers[-1].output]
        model.built = False

    return model
```

Comment: is the Flatten layer the same as a reshape(-1) ?

Comment: I have not used it as such, but as far as I know - the results should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use `model.fit(X, y)` to train on your dataset as explained here: https://keras.io/models/model/#fit

Additionally you should add a Flatten layer and a dense layer with an ouput shape of 1 to get the correct result shape.