# ValueError when Fine-tuning Inception_v3 in Keras

Tags: keras, dimensions, keras-layer

I am trying to fine-tune pre-trained Inceptionv3 in Keras for a multi-label (17) prediction problem.

Here's the code:

```
# create the base pre-trained model
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# add a new top layer
x = base_model.output
predictions = Dense(17, activation='sigmoid')(x)

# this is the model we will train
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

# we need to recompile the model for these modifications to take effect
# we use SGD with a low learning rate
from keras.optimizers import SGD
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', # We NEED binary here, since categorical_crossentropy l1 norms the output before calculating loss.
              optimizer=SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9))

# Fit the model (Add history so that the history may be saved)
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=128,
          epochs=1,
          verbose=1,
          callbacks=callbacks_list,
          validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid))
```

But I got into the following error message and had trouble deciphering what it is saying:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 4
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (1024, 17)

It seems to have something to do with that it doesn't like my one-hot encoding for the labels as target. But how do I get 4 dimensions target?

Comment: It seems that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764041/fine-tuning-pretrained-model-in-keras might have the answer?

Comment: Or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43386463/keras-vgg16-fine-tuning?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the code copied from https://keras.io/applications/ would not run out-of-the-box.
The following post has helped me:
[Keras VGG16 fine tuning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43386463/keras-vgg16-fine-tuning?rq=1)

The changes I need to make are the following:

1. Add in the input shape to the model definition `base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(299,299,3))`, and
2. Add a Flatten() layer to flatten the tensor output:

   `x = base_model.output
   x = Flatten()(x)
   predictions = Dense(17, activation='sigmoid')(x)`

Then the model works for me!